# Why IP tables is denying some explicitly specified as OK in rule?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.10

I've got top rule:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
... other rules, non-involving tap777 ...
-A INPUT -i tap777 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tap777 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

And I'm seeing this in the logs:

```
Oct 25 04:09:43 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx 1 kernel: [ 1824.841222] iptables denied: IN=tap777 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:c6:93:91:bb:b8:ae:ed:7b:d1:83:08:xx SRC=10.20.1.141 DST=10.20.1.1 LEN=343 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=4977 PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=323
```

To me it seems the denial is explicitly the same as the rule. Same dport, same proto, same *in* interface. So I only wonder if it has something to do with it not being the right chain?

`sudo iptables -L` gives:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:11900
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Could someone give me some insight into why this may be? Or something to try? 
Thanks!

Comment: You wrote the log before you accepted the packets.

Comment: So I need to move the reject-with lower down?

Comment: You need to move the _log_ line to where it makes sense.

Comment: Isn't the log line just telling the program what to do WHEN a reject happens? I.e. lower down?

Comment: No. Remember that iptables evaluates each rule in sequence.

Comment: iptables denied: is only a prefix for your log line you can change it to anything you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "

Is throttling packets and denying hence the logs.
 Bring it to second last in input chain. It will start working for sure.
Hope this helps! Please support and mark the answer as helped or answered if it did. Thanks :)